# Why does the 'submit' button on form keep refreshing the page even with presence of 'return false' at the end of the functioned called by the form?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, loops

In this assignment I'm supposed to "Write an application that searches for words in an array and creates a new array of found words and an array of search words that are not found. The application will display the new arrays of found and not-found words every time a new word is entered." I'm not sure what the problem is in my code, but every time I press 'submit on the web page it refreshes. Nothing is outputted correctly.

Unfortunately, this is an assignment I've left alone for a long time, but now that it's getting to be the end of the school year, I need to get it done. I do not have as good an understanding of JavaScript as I did when I was initially working on it. I fiddled with it for a bit, but couldn't figure out what was wrong. I will provide the relevant code from both the html and js file.

HTML File

```
<form id="searchFormId" action="6.2assignment2.html#" onsubmit="return assignment62_2Part1();">

  <label class="formLabel" for="entry">Entry: </label>
  <input id="entry" name="entry">

  <input type="submit" name="runExample" value="Enter" class="formatSubmit">

    </form>

    <!-- Ordered list of found words -->
    <h>Found Words</h>
    <ol id="foundWordsList"></ol>

    <!-- Ordered list of unfound words -->
    <h>Unfound Words</h>
    <ol id="unfoundWordsList"></ol>
```

JS File

```
var rightWords = ["JavaScript", "was", "developed", "by", "Brendan", "Eich",
                  "at", "Netscape", "as", "the", "in-page", "scripting",
                  "language", "for", "Navigator", "2.", "It", "is", "a",
                  "remarkably", "expressive", "dynamic", "programming",
                  "language.", "Because", "of", "its", "linkage", "to", "web",
                  "browsers", "it", "instantly", "became", "massively",
                  "popular.", "It", "never", "got", "a", "trial", "period",
                  "in", "which", "it", "could", "be", "corrected", "and",
                  "polished", "based", "on", "actual", "use", "The",
                  "language", "is", "powerful", "and", "flawed"];

// Get elements
var form = document.getElementById("searchFormId");
var foundList = document.getElementById("foundWordsList");
var unfoundList = document.getElementById("unfoundWordsList");

// Variable to hold user entry
var userEntry;

// Found/unfound word arrays
var foundWords = [];
var unfoundWords = [];

    function assignment62_2Part1() {
        // PART 1: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
        // What happens after Enter is pressed

        // Check if word was found
        var valueFound = false;

        // Reset output
        foundList.innerHTML = "";
        unfoundList.innerHTML = "";

        // Get user response 
        userEntry = form.entry.value;

        // Search and compare
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < rightWords; i++) {
            if (userEntry === rightWords[i]) {
                valueFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (valueFound) {
            foundWords.push(userEntry);
        } else {
                unfoundWords.push(userEntry);
        }   

        // Output
        for (i = 0; i < foundWords; i++) {
            foundList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[i] + "</li>";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < unfoundWords; i++) {
            unfoundList.innerHTML += "<li>" + unfoundWords[i] + "</li>";
        } 

        return false;
    }
```

I know I brought this onto myself by procrastinating, but I'm in a real bind! Any help is appreciated! Also, apologies if I've broken site etiquette. This is my first time looking at it much, not to mention making a post.

Also worth noting, this is for a semester-long class in high school, nothing fancy.

Edit: To clarify, I have been led to believe in the course of this curriculum that simple adding 'return false' at the end of the function that is called upon by the form is enough to prevent the page from being reloaded. I have completed other assignments where it's worked just fine, but doesn't in this one. I'm asking for help with finding what in my code is preventing it from doing what the assignment asks it to, as written in the first paragraph of the post.

Comment: that's what sumbittin a form does ...

Comment: “Why does this long button at the bottom of my keyboard keep putting spaces in my text?”

Comment: Search for "suppress default submit event" as for why this behavior is expected and how this can be suppressed - or better, use a `button` without such default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Hope it helps you. :)

```js
var rightWords = ["JavaScript", "was", "developed", "by", "Brendan", "Eich",
  "at", "Netscape", "as", "the", "in-page", "scripting",
  "language", "for", "Navigator", "2.", "It", "is", "a",
  "remarkably", "expressive", "dynamic", "programming",
  "language.", "Because", "of", "its", "linkage", "to", "web",
  "browsers", "it", "instantly", "became", "massively",
  "popular.", "It", "never", "got", "a", "trial", "period",
  "in", "which", "it", "could", "be", "corrected", "and",
  "polished", "based", "on", "actual", "use", "The",
  "language", "is", "powerful", "and", "flawed"
];

// Get elements
var form = document.getElementById("searchFormId");
var foundList = document.getElementById("foundWordsList");
var unfoundList = document.getElementById("unfoundWordsList");

// Variable to hold user entry
var userEntry;

// Found/unfound word arrays
var foundWords = [];
var unfoundWords = [];

function assignment62_2Part1() {

  // Check if word was found
  var valueFound = false;

  // Reset output
  foundList.innerHTML = "";
  unfoundList.innerHTML = "";

  // Get user response 
  userEntry = entry.value;

  // Search and compare
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < rightWords.length; i++) {
    if (userEntry === rightWords[i]) {
      valueFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (valueFound) {
    foundWords.push(userEntry);
  } else {
    unfoundWords.push(userEntry);
  }

  // Output
  for (i = 0; i < foundWords.length; i++) {
    foundList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[i] + "</li>";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < unfoundWords.length; i++) {
    unfoundList.innerHTML += "<li>" + unfoundWords[i] + "</li>";
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<label class="formLabel" for="entry">Entry: </label>
<input id="entry" name="entry">

<input type="button" name="runExample" value="Enter" class="formatSubmit" onclick="assignment62_2Part1();" />

<!-- Ordered list of found words -->
<h4>Found Words</h4>
<ol id="foundWordsList"></ol>

<!-- Ordered list of unfound words -->
<h4>Unfound Words</h4>
<ol id="unfoundWordsList"></ol>
```

Here is a more advanced and easier version to help you improve your code in the future :)

```js
var rightWords = ["JavaScript", "was", "developed", "by", "Brendan", "Eich",
  "at", "Netscape", "as", "the", "in-page", "scripting",
  "language", "for", "Navigator", "2.", "It", "is", "a",
  "remarkably", "expressive", "dynamic", "programming",
  "language.", "Because", "of", "its", "linkage", "to", "web",
  "browsers", "it", "instantly", "became", "massively",
  "popular.", "It", "never", "got", "a", "trial", "period",
  "in", "which", "it", "could", "be", "corrected", "and",
  "polished", "based", "on", "actual", "use", "The",
  "language", "is", "powerful", "and", "flawed"
];

var foundWords = [];
var unfoundWords = [];

btn.onclick = ()=>{
    (rightWords.indexOf(entry.value) > 0 ? foundWords : unfoundWords)
        .push("<li>" + entry.value + "</li>");

    foundWordsList.innerHTML = foundWords.join('');
    unfoundWordsList.innerHTML = unfoundWords.join('');
}
```

```html
<label class="formLabel" for="entry">Entry: </label>
<input id="entry" name="entry">

<input type="button" id='btn' name="runExample" value="Enter" class="formatSubmit" />

<!-- Ordered list of found words -->
<h4>Found Words</h4>
<ol id="foundWordsList"></ol>

<!-- Ordered list of unfound words -->
<h4>Unfound Words</h4>
<ol id="unfoundWordsList"></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `<button type="button> </button>` in your html it shouldn't refresh the page and you may use js click events on your button to continue the application running next steps. 
If you want require elements of the form to continue you may use js to make the button have a not-allowed cursor style if the form isn't filled.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically the opportunity to use a **set**
 => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

but you also may use **Array​.prototype​.includes()**
=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

to diseable page reload you have to use : **Event​.prevent​Default()**
=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

but this one works on the form, not on the button, has I show it in my snippet :

```js
const
    form        = document.getElementById('searchFormId')
  , foundList   = document.getElementById('foundWordsList')
  , unfoundList = document.getElementById('unfoundWordsList')
  , rightWords  = new Set(
    [ 'JavaScript', 'was', 'developed', 'by', 'Brendan', 'Eich'
    , 'at', 'Netscape', 'as', 'the', 'in-page', 'scripting'
    , 'language', 'for', 'Navigator', '2.', 'It', 'is', 'a'
    , 'remarkably', 'expressive', 'dynamic', 'programming'
    , 'language.', 'Because', 'of', 'its', 'linkage', 'to', 'web'
    , 'browsers', 'it', 'instantly', 'became', 'massively'
    , 'popular.', 'It', 'never', 'got', 'a', 'trial', 'period'
    , 'in', 'which', 'it', 'could', 'be', 'corrected', 'and'
    , 'polished', 'based', 'on', 'actual', 'use', 'The'
    , 'language', 'is', 'powerful', 'and', 'flawed'
    ])
  ;

form.onsubmit = function(evt)
{
  evt.preventDefault();  // disable form sending action
  let
    userEntry  = form.entry.value
  , valueFound = rightWords.has( userEntry )
  , LI_elm     = document.createElement('li')
  ;
  form.entry.value   = '';
  LI_elm.textContent = userEntry;

  if (valueFound) { foundList.appendChild( LI_elm )   }
  else            { unfoundList.appendChild( LI_elm ) }
}
```

```html
<form id="searchFormId" >

  <label class="formLabel" for="entry">Entry: </label>
  <input id="entry" name="entry">

  <button type="submit"  class="formatSubmit"> Enter </button>

</form>

<!-- Ordered list of found words -->
<h2>Found Words</h2>
<ol id="foundWordsList"></ol>

<!-- Ordered list of unfound words -->
<h2>Unfound Words</h2>
<ol id="unfoundWordsList"></ol>
```